# Elements and plot of a complex set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$M = \{w^k + w | k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ with $$w = \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$$

I'm suppossed to figure out how many elements there are in the set and then sketch it in the complex plane. 
The polar form of $w$ is $$w = cos(-\frac{\pi}{4}) + isin(-\frac{\pi}{4})$$

How do I solve this problem analytically? I'm thinking that there are $k$ elements in the set, but I don't know how to prove it. 
Plotting would require me to know all values of the set (or at least a formula with a variable $\in \mathbb{Z}$) .

There must be an easier and more mathematical way to figure it out than solving for $0$ to $k$ until you get repetitive values, right?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $w^8 = 1$ so $w^k = w^{k \bmod 8}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I have since figured out the solution to the problem myself. Finding out that there were 8 elements was kind of trivial, but calculating each of them was annoying none the less.